# Is it possible to place 2 buttons in List view

Tags: java, android

### ListView

### [Text] [Button 1][Button 2]

### [Text] [Button 1][Button 2]

... (and so on) ...

Button 1 should be like Check Box and other button which allows to redirect on other page

Is above mentioned thing possible??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you tried wrapping them (each row) in a container? (Linear Layout for example). That should achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Each row in a list view can have anything your heart desires. A row is basically defined as its own layout, and you can define the layout as you wish. In your case, you probably want to do a RelativeLayout. Check out the examples, they come pretty close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your ListView row to contain a CheckedTextView and a Button ina Linear Layout.

In \layout\ folder, define your customised my_row.xml, roughly so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"> 
<CheckedTextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    /> 
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Then for populating your ListView, give this in your Adapter.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_row, strings);
myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```